# Cannot set AP via wpa_supplicant on rtl8192eu

Tags: linux, wifi, realtek, access-point

I am using Imx 6dl board with linux kernal 4.1.15 I connected tlwn823n wifi dongle to it , which has rtl8192eu chipset , I compiled the driver for the same and inserted .ko files , here are the results for lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 2357:0109
```

and here are the results by giving dmesg

```
[10717.465249] RTW:
               usb_endpoint_descriptor(0):
[10717.469272] RTW: bLength=7
[10717.470886] RTW: bDescriptorType=5
[10717.476422] RTW: bEndpointAddress=84
[10717.478764] RTW: wMaxPacketSize=512
[10717.481663] RTW: bInterval=0
[10717.483282] RTW: RT_usb_endpoint_is_bulk_in = 4
[10717.486530] RTW:
               usb_endpoint_descriptor(1):
[10717.489715] RTW: bLength=7
[10717.492009] RTW: bDescriptorType=5
[10717.494120] RTW: bEndpointAddress=5
[10717.496309] RTW: wMaxPacketSize=512
[10717.498496] RTW: bInterval=0
[10717.500116] RTW: RT_usb_endpoint_is_bulk_out = 5
[10717.504533] RTW:
               usb_endpoint_descriptor(2):
[10717.507694] RTW: bLength=7
[10717.509105] RTW: bDescriptorType=5
[10717.511778] RTW: bEndpointAddress=6
[10717.513969] RTW: wMaxPacketSize=512
[10717.516404] RTW: bInterval=0
[10717.517991] RTW: RT_usb_endpoint_is_bulk_out = 6
[10717.522047] RTW:
               usb_endpoint_descriptor(3):
[10717.525195] RTW: bLength=7
[10717.526759] RTW: bDescriptorType=5
[10717.528863] RTW: bEndpointAddress=87
[10717.531815] RTW: wMaxPacketSize=64
[10717.534008] RTW: bInterval=3
[10717.535594] RTW: RT_usb_endpoint_is_int_in = 7, Interval = 3
[10717.540098] RTW:
               usb_endpoint_descriptor(4):
[10717.543905] RTW: bLength=7
[10717.545357] RTW: bDescriptorType=5
[10717.547517] RTW: bEndpointAddress=8
[10717.549709] RTW: wMaxPacketSize=512
[10717.552706] RTW: bInterval=0
[10717.554293] RTW: RT_usb_endpoint_is_bulk_out = 8
[10717.557687] RTW: nr_endpoint=5, in_num=2, out_num=3

[10717.561940] RTW: USB_SPEED_HIGH
[10717.563943] RTW: CHIP TYPE: RTL8192E
[10717.567504] RTW: read_chip_version_8192e 0xF0 = 0xc441135
[10717.572265] RTW: rtw_hal_config_rftype RF_Type is 2 TotalTxPath is 2
[10717.577680] RTW: Chip Version Info: CHIP_8192E_Normal_Chip_SMIC_B_CUT_2T2R_RomVer(0)
[10717.584633] RTW: _ConfigChipOutEP_8192E OutEpQueueSel(0x07), OutEpNumber(3)
[10717.590682] RTW: Boot from EFUSE, Autoload OK !
[10717.765559] RTW: HW EFUSE
[10717.766930] RTW: 0x000: 29 81 00 7C 01 40 03 00    40 74 04 50 14 00 00 00
[10717.774098] RTW: 0x010: 29 29 29 2B 2B 2B 2C 2C    2C 2D 2D F2 EF EF FF FF
[10717.780178] RTW: 0x020: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.786643] RTW: 0x030: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF 2A 2A 2A 2B 2B 2B
[10717.792822] RTW: 0x040: 2D 2D 2C 2C 2C F2 EF EF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.798834] RTW: 0x050: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.805093] RTW: 0x060: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.811441] RTW: 0x070: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.817402] RTW: 0x080: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.823522] RTW: 0x090: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.829522] RTW: 0x0a0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.835781] RTW: 0x0b0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    A2 0F 21 00 00 00 FF FF
[10717.842045] RTW: 0x0c0: FF 01 00 10 00 00 00 FF    00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.848058] RTW: 0x0d0: 57 23 09 01 E7 47 02 D0    37 45 17 5B B6 0A 03 52
[10717.854350] RTW: 0x0e0: 65 61 6C 74 65 6B 20 0E    03 38 30 32 2E 31 31 6E
[10717.860353] RTW: 0x0f0: 20 4E 49 43 20 00 00 FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.866571] RTW: 0x100: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.872786] RTW: 0x110: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 0D    03 00 05 00 30 00 00 00
[10717.878744] RTW: 0x120: 00 93 FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.885027] RTW: 0x130: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.891021] RTW: 0x140: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.897208] RTW: 0x150: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.903432] RTW: 0x160: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.909240] RTW: 0x170: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.915619] RTW: 0x180: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.921857] RTW: 0x190: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.927680] RTW: 0x1a0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.933987] RTW: 0x1b0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.939824] RTW: 0x1c0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.946155] RTW: 0x1d0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.952491] RTW: 0x1e0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
[10717.958317] RTW: 0x1f0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF    FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF

[10717.964889] RTW: EEPROM ID=0x8129
[10717.966919] RTW: VID = 0x2357, PID = 0x0109
[10717.969803] RTW: Customer ID: 0x00, SubCustomer ID: 0xCD
[10717.974732] RTW: Hal_ReadPowerSavingMode8192E...bHWPwrPindetect(0)-bHWPowerdown(0) ,bSupportRemoteWakeup(1)
[10717.983447] RTW: ### PS params=>  power_mgnt(2),usbss_enable(0) ###
[10717.988586] RTW: EEPROMRegulatory = 0x1
[10717.991519] RTW: Board Type: Dongle or WIFI only Module
[10717.995473] RTW: Hal_EfuseParseBTCoexistInfo8192E: Disable BT-coex, wifi ant_num=2
[10718.002271] RTW: hal_com_config_channel_plan chplan:0x22
[10718.006288] RTW: crystal_cap: 0x f
[10718.008389] RTW: ThermalMeter = 0x21
[10718.010665] RTW: SWAS: bHwAntDiv = 0, TRxAntDivType = 0
[10718.015442] RTW: pHalData->ExternalPA_2G = 0 , pHalData->ExternalLNA_2G = 0
[10718.021368] RTW: pHalData->TypeGLNA is 0x0
[10718.024168] RTW: pHalData->rfe_type is 0xff
[10718.031799] RTW: kfree flag:0
[10718.033480] RTW: rtw_hal_read_chip_info in 450 ms
[10718.036926] RTW: init_channel_set((null)) ChannelPlan ID:0x22, ch num:11
[10718.044386] RTW: NR_RECVBUFF: 8
[10718.046241] RTW: MAX_RECVBUF_SZ: 32768
[10718.048800] RTW: NR_PREALLOC_RECV_SKB: 8
[10718.052499] RTW: rtw_alloc_macid((null)) if1, mac_addr:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff macid:1
[10718.058902] RTW: IQK FW offload:disable
[10718.061994] RTW: rtw_regsty_chk_target_tx_power_valid return _FALSE for band:0, path:0, rs:0, t:-1
[10718.069946] RTW: pwrctrlpriv.bSupportRemoteWakeup~~~~~~
[10718.074328] RTW: pwrctrlpriv.bSupportRemoteWakeup~~~[1]~~~
[10718.078578] RTW: can't get autopm:
[10718.080870] RTW: rtw_macaddr_cfg mac addr:d0:37:45:17:5b:b6
[10718.085720] RTW: bDriverStopped:True, bSurpriseRemoved:False, bup:0, hw_init_completed:0
[10718.093050] RTW: rtw_ndev_init(wlan0) if1 mac_addr=d0:37:45:17:5b:b6
[10718.098562] RTW: rtw_ndev_notifier_call(wlan0) state:16
[10718.107036] RTW: rtw_ndev_notifier_call(wlan0) state:5
```

I have compiled wpa_supplicant , rfkill and got the executable files which i have placed in /usr/bin/

My wpa_supplicant.conf is

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
eapol_version=1
ap_scan=2
fast_reauth=1
network={
        ssid="simple"
        psk="12345678"
        priority=5
}
```

but when i give this command

```
 wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

but I am getting this error

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

Kindly help me solving this error.

Comment: It's highly probable that your dongle does not support AP out of the box. BTW, I do not read you installed the needed firmware ( rtl8188eufw.bin )

Comment: hi @MC68020 i have compiled the driver which is given by the tp link , it only generates 8192eu.ko file which i have put it on the board .